# Laravel web guard login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel and try to sign in a user with the web guard like this (my default is api):

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],false,false))
            {
                var_dump('success');     //return api key
            }
             var_dump('no success');
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            dd('error');
        }
    }
}
```

But the the result is always 'no success'  when I check the `$request->email` and the `$request->password`
with dd the result is equal to my database record. What could be wrong?

This is my routes file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/login', 'api\v1\UserController@login');
});
```

Comment: What's the laravel version you are using?

Comment: if 5.2, both `web` and `api` have the same provider?